# Simulating has_many :through with Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongodb, mongoid, data-modeling

I'm trying to create an event platform using MongoDB as the db. I want a many-to-many relationship between `Events` and `Users`. The thing is, I want there to be properties in the relationship (e.g., `Users` can either be confirmed or unconfirmed for a specific `Event`). I realize this would be ideally suited for an RDBMS, but I'm using MongoDB for reasons that I'm taking advantage elsewhere and I would prefer to continue using it.

What I would like is for each `Event` to embed many `Guests`, which belong to `Users`. That way, I can see which users are attending an event quickly and with only one query. However, I would also like to see which `Events` a `User` is attending quickly, so I would like each `User` to have an array of `Event` ids.

Here is a code summary.

```rb
# user of the application
class User
  has_many :events
end

# event that users can choose to attend
class Event
  embeds_many :guests
  has_many :users, :through => :guests      # Won't work
end

# guests for an event
class Guest
  field :confirmed?, type: Boolean

  embedded_in :event
  belongs_to  :user
end


# Ideal use pattern
u = User.create
e = Event.create
e.guests.create(:user => u, :confirmed => true)
```

With the ideal use pattern, `e` has a `Guest` with a reference to `u` and `u` has a reference to `e`.

I know the `has_many :through` line won't work. Any suggestions as to how to get similar functionality? I was thinking of using an `after_create` callback in `Guest` to add a reference to the `Event` in `User`, but that seems pretty hacky.

Maybe I've gone down the wrong path. Suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just store the event ids in a array on the user.

You have to manage the array when the event changes or the user is removed from the event for some reason. But that is the trade off.

User.events can then be found with a single db call.

Look at [observers](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/callbacks.html#observers) to manage the association.

Comment: I just saw your answer. I posted how I ended up solving my problem, but using observers would have been cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, nodrog, the link are broken.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using callbacks in the models to accomplish I wanted. Here's what it looks like.

**Edit:** I just saw nodrog's answer. Yeah, using observers would probably have been neater, I  didn't know about them. Thanks!

```rb
# user of the application
class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :events, inverse_of: nil, dependent: :nullify
end

# event that users can choose to attend
class Event
  embeds_many :guests
  index 'guests.user_id', unique: true
  before_destroy :cleanup_guest_references

  def cleanup_guest_references
    self.guests.each do |guest|
      guest.destroy
    end
  end
end

# guests for an event
class Guest
  field :confirmed?, type: Boolean

  embedded_in :event, :inverse_of => :guests
  belongs_to  :user

  after_create :add_event_for_user
  before_destroy :remove_event_for_user

  private
    def add_event_for_user
      self.user.events.push(self.event)
    end
    def remove_event_for_user
      self.user.events.delete self.event
      self.user.save
    end
end
```

Comment: Can someone say what the best way to do some like this?

Comment: I think callbacks make sense. Very similar to observers.